# Correct place to pass in parameters in Selenium testing?

Tags: c#, selenium

What is the "proper" way to pass in parameters?

Code snippet below (pieces have been removed that aren't relevant)...

I am passing in the login parameters in the [TestMethod] itself, and not in the LoginPage class object.  Is that the right way to do this?  Or, should I be passing the strings into the LoginPage class itself?  (I realized there are other ways where I don't need to hard-code anywhere, but I am strictly referring to this hard-code scenario)

```
class LoginPage
{

    IWebDriver driver;

    By username = By.Id("user_login");
    By password = By.XPath(".//*[@id='user_pass']");
    By loginButton = By.Name("wp-submit");


    public void loginToWordpress(string userid, string pass)
    {
        driver.FindElement(username).SendKeys(userid);
        driver.FindElement(password).SendKeys(pass);
    }


}
```

and the corresponding test....

```
   [TestMethod]
        public void assertPageSource()
        {
            LoginPage login = new LoginPage(driver);
            login.loginToWordpress("admin", "demo123");
            login.clickOnLoginButton();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I can think of below ways:

1.@DataProvider annotation from TestNG can be used for passing parameters
Here's a good example : https://www.edureka.co/blog/dataprovider-in-testng/

2.Passing parameters using an excel file - you can save the username and passwords in the file(although not the best practice) and use the file for passing parameters. Apache POI is used for reading/writing Excel file in Java, not sure about C#

3.Create a table with usernames and passwords, connect to the table through your code and use the values as parameters

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this two articles --

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/SeleniumHQ/selenium/PageObjects.md

https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/c-sharp/encapsulation-oops-principle/